# Functional processing of Scala streams without OutOfMemory errors

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is it possible to apply functional programming to Scala streams such that the stream is processed sequentially, but the already processed part of the stream can be garbage collected?

For example, I define a `Stream` that contains the numbers from `start` to `end`:

```
def fromToStream(start: Int, end: Int) : Stream[Int] = {
  if (end < start) Stream.empty
  else start #:: fromToStream(start+1, end)
}
```

If I sum up the values in a functional style:

```
println(fromToStream(1,10000000).reduceLeft(_+_))
```

I get an `OutOfMemoryError` - perhaps since the stackframe of the call to `reduceLeft` holds a reference to the head of the stream. But if I do this in iterative style, it works:

```
var sum = 0
for (i <- fromToStream(1,10000000)) {
  sum += i
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a functional style without getting an `OutOfMemory`?

**UPDATE**: This was [a bug in scala](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2239) that is fixed now. So this is more or less out of date now.

Comment: Although this in no way answers your question, I find that the `#::` syntax for streams is much more readable over `Stream.cons`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can. The trick is to use tail recursive methods, so that the local stack frame contains the only reference to the `Stream` instance. Since the method is tail-recursive, the local reference to the previous `Stream` head will be erased once it recursively calls itself, thus enabling the GC to collect the start of the `Stream` as you go.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.r23459-b20101108091606 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import collection.immutable.Stream
import collection.immutable.Stream

scala> import annotation.tailrec
import annotation.tailrec

scala> @tailrec def last(s: Stream[Int]): Int = if (s.tail.isEmpty) s.head else last(s.tail)
last: (s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int])Int

scala> last(Stream.range(0, 100000000))                                                                             
res2: Int = 99999999
```

Also, you must ensure that the thing you pass to the method `last` above has only one reference on the stack. If you store a `Stream` into a local variable or value, it will not be garbage collected when you call the `last` method, since its argument is not the only reference left to `Stream`. The code below runs out of memory.

```
scala> val s = Stream.range(0, 100000000)                                                                           
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)                                                            

scala> last(s)                                                                                                      
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space                                              
        at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.encodePath(ParseUtil.java:84)                                                      
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(URLClassPath.java:674)                                     
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:759)                                       
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:169)                                                 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)                                                   
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)                                               
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)                                               
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)                                                    
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)                                            
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)                                                    
        at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$onErr$1$1.apply(Interpreter.scala:978)                      
        at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$onErr$1$1.apply(Interpreter.scala:976)                      
        at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:80)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request.loadAndRun(Interpreter.scala:984)                                    
        at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.loadAndRunReq$1(Interpreter.scala:579)                                       
        at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.scala:599)                                             
        at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.scala:576)
        at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.reallyInterpret$1(InterpreterLoop.scala:472)                             
        at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.interpretStartingWith(InterpreterLoop.scala:515)                         
        at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.command(InterpreterLoop.scala:362)
        at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.processLine$1(InterpreterLoop.scala:243)
        at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.repl(InterpreterLoop.scala:249)
        at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.main(InterpreterLoop.scala:559)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:75)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:31)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

To summarize:

1. Use tail-recursive methods
2. Annotate them as tail-recursive
3. When you call them, ensure that their argument is the only reference to the `Stream`

EDIT:

Note that this also works and does not result in an out of memory error:

```
scala> def s = Stream.range(0, 100000000)                                                   
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]

scala> last(s)                                                                              
res1: Int = 99999999
```

EDIT2:

<strike>And in the case of `reduceLeft` that you require, you would have to define a helper method with an accumulator argument for the result.</strike>

For reduceLeft, you need an accumulator argument, which you can set to a certain value using default arguments. A simplified example:

```
scala> @tailrec def rcl(s: Stream[Int], acc: Int = 0): Int = if (s.isEmpty) acc else rcl(s.tail, acc + s.head)
rcl: (s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int],acc: Int)Int

scala> rcl(Stream.range(0, 10000000))
res6: Int = -2014260032
```

Comment: Where would you defined the helper method? If in an inner method of `reduceLeft`, wouldn't the caller of the helper method risk holding on to the head of the stream?

Comment: Hmmm. Good point - he would indeed. And tail call optimization can only be applied to recursive methods. You're right. But one can then play with default parameters. See my 2nd edit.

Comment: I have the same problem of OutOfMemory, but using stream.foreach - how can I solve it?

Answer (score 19):

When I started learning about `Stream` I thought this was cool. Then I realized `Iterator` is what I want to use nearly all the time.

In case you do need `Stream` but want to make `reduceLeft` work:

```
fromToStream(1,10000000).toIterator.reduceLeft(_ + _)
```

If you try the line above, it will garbage collect just fine. I have found that using Stream is tricky as it's easy to hold on to the head without realizing it. Sometimes the standard lib will hold on to it for you - in very subtle ways.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at Scalaz's [ephemeral streams](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/27c5452256cdc99e07740900e096268082f477f8/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/EphemeralStream.scala).

Comment: A snippet would be great to see how ephemeral streams apply to this particular question. The link you provide points to a source file that has no comment.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this is [a bug](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2239#comment:5) in the current implementation of reduceLeft. The problem is that reduceLeft calls foldLeft, and thus the stackframe of reduceLeft holds a reference to the head of the stream during the whole call. foldLeft uses tail-recursion to avoid this problem. Compare:

```
(1 to 10000000).toStream.foldLeft(0)(_+_)
(1 to 10000000).toStream.reduceLeft(_+_)
```

These are semantically equivalent. In Scala version 2.8.0 the call to foldLeft works, but the call to reduceLeft throws an OutOfMemory. If reduceLeft would do its own work, this problem would not occur.