# Stream in production code

Tags: scala

Do people really use Scala's Stream class in production code, or is it primarily of academic interest?

Comment: What is so special about `Stream` that makes you ask this question? Why shouldn't one use it in production code?

Comment: It's easy to exhaust memory for one. Also I seem to recall reading that its implementation is showing its age. So I'm just curious whether people really use it for things beyond the Euler Project. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem with `Stream`, except when people use it to replace `Iterator` -- as opposed to replacing `List`, which is the collection most similar to it. In that particular case, one has to be careful in its use. On the other hand, one has to be careful using `Iterator` as well, since each element can only be iterated through once.

So, since both have their own problems, why single out `Stream`'s? I daresay it's simply that people are used to `Iterator` from Java, whereas `Stream` is a functional thing.

Comment: Well, Stream does seem to have its problems, such as when used in reduceLeft.

Comment: A lot of good answers to this question; this one was for me the most helpful, since I didn't quite grok that using it like a List, not an Iterator, is the right approach.  Thanks to everybody who replied.

Answer (score 3):

Even though I wrote that *[Iterator is what I want to use nearly all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132924/functional-processing-of-scala-streams-without-outofmemory-errors/4134541#4134541)* I do use `Stream` in production code. I just don't automatically assume that the cells are garbage collected.

Sometimes `Stream` fits the problem perfectly. I think the api gives [some good examples](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html) where recursion is involved...

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?27). This blog post describes how to use Scala Streams (along with memory mapped file) to read large files (1-2G) efficiently.

I did not try it yet but the solution looks reasonable. Stream provides a nice abstraction on top of the low level `ByteBuffer` Java API to handle a memory mapped file as a sequence of records.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I use it, although it tends to be for something like this:

```
(as.toStream collect expensiveConversionToB) match {
  case b #:: _ => //found my expensive b
  case _       =>
}
```

Of course, I might use a non-strict view and a `find` for this example

Comment: I guess what motivates me is the realization that Stream is so fragile in terms of memory use, that I would shudder to find it in production code, unless there was no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only reason not to use `Stream`s is that it can be tricky to ensure the JVM isn't keeping references to early conses around, one approach I've used that's fairly nice is to build up a `Stream` and immediately convert it to an `Iterator` for actual use.  It loses a little of `Stream`'s nice properties on the use side especially with respect to backtracking, but if you're only going to make one pass over the result it's frequently easier to build a structure this way than to contort into the `hasNext`/`next()` model of `Iterator` directly.