# Is there a data structure like stream, but weak?

Tags: list, scala, stream

Weak as in weak references. Basically, I need a sequence of numbers where some of them can be unallocated when they aren't needed anymore.

Comment: You should be glad you don't have a weak stream (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132924/functional-processing-of-scala-streams-without-outofmemory-errors

Comment: @Sciss Sorry, couldn't find anything when I searched... well, that happens sometimes, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scalaz.EphemeralStream is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Views provide you with a lazy collection, where each value is computed as it is needed.

Comment: Yes. I already have a lazy collection (Stream), but I need it to be weak too.

Comment: The whole point of the question... gotcha!  Thanks.  I'll leave my answer here for others to see these comments.  Can someone perhaps explain why Views are not weak?

Comment: The distinction is that views do not cache computed elements at all, while a weak stream will cache its elements until they are garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create an `Iterable` instead of a `Stream`. Your `Iterable` needs to provide an `iterator` method, which returns an iterator with `hasNext` and `next` methods.

When you loop over the `Iterable`, `hasNext` and `next` will be called to generate the elements as they are needed, but they are not stored anywhere (like a `Stream` does).

Simple example:

```
class Numbers extends Iterable[Int] {
  def iterator = new Iterator[Int] {
    private var num = -1

    def hasNext = num < 99
    def next = { num += 1; num }
  }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't help much, because I need a stream for two reasons: functional programming (= not iterators) and memoization (not iterables).

Comment: @Anonymous - note that `Iterable` has most Scala collection methods (including `foreach`, `map`, `filter`, `foldLeft` etc) so you can use it for func programming just like any other collection, and memoization: I thought you wanted something that does *not* retain the generated values?

Comment: It should retain them, just not permanent. Look at (I think) java.lang.ref.WeakReference.